# What is the meaning of the idiom "blanket judgment"?

Tags: idioms

The context is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmzH9MHKC7s) (YouTube) on 1:44

n.b. I've tried to make googling and I didn't find an answer.

Comment: It's a *figurative* usage, alluding to the fact that a *blanket* covers *everything* [under it]. Consider over 55,000 written references to [a blanket of snow](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22blanket+of+snow%22) (which pretty much covers everything in the region where it's snowing).

Comment: Assiduous: In my own cack-handed way I'm trying to *teach* you to fish rather than *giving* you a fish! I don't know what your own native language is, but I'm sure it will make extensive use of "metaphors, figurative speech". Your equivalent to *blanket* might not happen to be used metaphorically the same way as the English word, but just as law enforcement workers know they have to *follow the money*, if you want to gain proficiency in English you really have to ***follow the metaphor***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Feminists place this **blanket judgement** over all men

in other words, **all men** are thought of in the same way, covered like a blanket, even though they are not all the same.  Another idiom for this is

> **painted with the same brush**
>   [**tarred with the same brush**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tar+with+the+same+brush)

Comment: I haven't often encountered ***painted** with the same brush*, but *tarred with the same brush* is a good "synonym" because it also implies a *negative* assessment (as with *blanket judgement*), whereas a ***generalization*** could refer to a *positive* oversimplification as well as a negative one.

Comment: I think the AmE use of **painted** is to stay away from the other connotations that **tarred** may have, as in tarred and feathered...

Comment: Hmm. I think [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tarred+with+the+same+brush%2Cpainted+with+the+same+brush&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctarred%20with%20the%20same%20brush%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpainted%20with%20the%20same%20brush%3B%2Cc0), with noticeable "spikes" after WW1, WW2, and recent decades supports my gut feel that ***painted*** only exists at all because a small number of people "mis-reproduce" an idiomatic expression that they hadn't heard before.

Comment: I've heard "painted with the same brush" almost exclusively in AmE where I've lived. My thoughts surrounding "tarred with the same brush" are the revolution and "tarring and feathering"

Comment: @Alex K: Without looking it up, I'd be pretty sure "tarred with the same brush" either derives from or shares ancestry with "tarring and feathering". The point of my previous comment was simply that population intermingling by soldiers in world wars, and the recent upsurge in ["Limited English Proficient"](http://www.migrationpolicy.org/programs/data-hub/us-immigration-trends#lep) US residents lead to more people making "copying errors" with idiomatic usages like this (that they hadn't heard before).

Comment: @FumbleFingers definitely. I agree!